# Plain and Simple XML template for Blogspot without styling

Tags: html, xml, blogger

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>
    <meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>
      <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'/>
    <b:else/>
      <meta content='width=1100' name='viewport'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>

    <b:skin><![CDATA[/*

]]></b:skin>

  
  </head>

  <body>
  <b:section class='navbar' id='navbar' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
<b:widget id='Navbar1' locked='true' title='Navbar' type='Navbar'/>
</b:section>


<div style='margin-top:700px; '>
<br/>
<center><b><font color='#ffffff'>© All Rights Resrved by <a href='http://a2alltopics.blogspot.in/' style="color: #ffffff">Shurvir Mori</a> 2014.</font></b></center>
</div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

This is a basic layout code for a blogger template. This code currently is displayed as blank on the blogger. I want this code to present the posts on the home page and when clicked on the post link, it is required to display the post. No any styling required. (Yeah, I don't know XML, please
help me out :( )

Answer (score 0):

Blogger blank theme:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' b:defaultwidgetversion='2' b:layoutsVersion='3' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>
    
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
    
    <title><data:view.title/></title>
    
    <b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='yes'>
      <b:widget id="Blog1" locked="true" type="Blog" />
    </b:section>
  </body>
</html>
```